# Why was this question temporarily locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-posts

Regarding [reset variable in recursive method back to zero after its done/before its called again?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74451619/1552534)

After a few comments and one answer, this question was temporarily locked because of *disputes about this content.*  The moderator locked it for 3 days. I agree that is can be frustrating when someone (not me in this case) provides an answer only to have the OP delete the question.  That is why I voted to undelete it.  But I can't imagine what disputes are being discussed. I have seen far worse questions that don't get locked, and among those were where the OP's have seen fit to deleted their question after several answers get posted.

Although it may be wishful thinking, I would have just waited and given the OP a chance to read the comments and make clarifying edits to the question, perhaps eliciting more answers.  Just wondering what would constitute a lock of this type for this particular question.

Comment: From the comments by a moderator: *"Please don't delete questions that received answers"* Locking the question also stops the OP deleting it.

Comment: Looking at the (remaining, I guess) questions from OP it looks like they have a habbit of deleting or defacing their questions after getting an answer. So I guess a mod had to step in to stop that.

Comment: @Larnu I saw that.  But why lock the question? How is locking for 3 days denying comments and questions going to help.

Comment: @Tom, that may be the case.  Since I can't see the deletion history of others I would not have known.

Comment: Deleting answered questions in general is a minefield. I haven't checked, but there's a chance they mass-deleted posts, which isn't allowed. Seeing more posts and deleted posts, which lends credibility to that

Comment: @WJS I can't either, that is why I wrote "remaining, I guess", because I can only assume that. But two questions got locked and one got defaced by OP.

Comment: *How is locking for 3 days denying comments and questions going to help."* As I said, locking stops the OP deleting the question. Locks are all or nothing, so to stop the OP deleting the content the question was locked, which (unfortunately) also stops comments being made.

Comment: @Larnu *Locks are all or nothing, so to stop the OP deleting the content the question was locked, which (unfortunately) also stops comments being made.*   Didn't know about the all or nothing.  I would have thought there would be more granularity.

Comment: Nope, locks are notoriously bad. It's very often all or nothing, which does indeed mean it's a heavy hammer to use. But it's often the only usable hammer, which doesn't really help the situation

Comment: Well, we could also suspend the user instead... but that's more work.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Well, you work with what you have.  This has been enlightening.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I must be overlooking something. Why is it more work to suspend a user than to lock every question that the user might want to delete?

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger Just a guess: maybe there is more internal documentation required when a mod wants to suspend a user, so other mods and community managers can tell why a user has been suspended for the given amount of time when someone asks them, for example via "contact us".

Comment: @E_net4 As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334172/), it is not possible to suspend a user without sending them a message. Locking a post is just a couple clicks. Writing a moderator message takes a lot of careful thought and writing time. Also, [as described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210057/), these moderator messages also notify all of a site's moderators when sent. That's a lot of notifications if a lock and comment might do.

Comment: “But why lock the question?” - Author asked a question, received a detailed answer, then deleted their question. Asking a question then deleting it is toxic behavior, the question was locked, to prevent it from being deleted by the author.

Comment: @SecurityHound Except I have seen quite a few questions that were deleted by the author after answers were provided.  This is the first time I  have seen a lock for that reason.  So I figured it must be some other reason. Hence the question.

Comment: A "one off" isn't likely to get the mods attention, @WJS . Deleting 2 questions and defacing a 3rd is, however, likely to attract attention.

Comment: @IanCampbell That is odd, considering how I've seen mods handing suspensions quite swiftly in some cases. At least there ought to be a set of templates from common suspension reasons, and this would likely be one of them.

Comment: Now they are exhibiting other bad behavior, adding [CLOSED} to the text, and changing the question  see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74451619/revisions